# Alternatives to Spirit Gum?

Tags: adhesives

Spirit Gum is a brush on liquid adhesive used for attaching prosthetics, and other special effects to the body without harming the skin or the prosthetic. However, stores only carry it around Halloween here. Is there an alternative to it that I could use, that won't damage me or or the special effects, that I could pick up at a crafting store like Hobby Lobby or even a place like Walmart?

Comment: Amazon and eBay both have this.

Comment: @scanny online purchase isn't an option for me right now

Comment: It's a long shot, but if you are lucky enough to have a magic store in your area, you'll probably find the source of many special effects products. Our town has had a shop for a couple of decades and the proprietor caters to professional theatre performers, carrying makeup kits and spirit gum, as well as latex products used for such purposes.

Comment: The only other option I've seen in the theatrical supply shops around here is Prosthetic Adhesive, which is stronger and of a somewhat different chemical composition (allowing use by people who may react to Spirit Gum, and also requiring a specific remover). If you have theatrical supply shops, check those, but very little that's generally available is both skin-safe and non-damaging to delicate prosthetic pieces.

Comment: @AllisonC with a little expansion and research, that would be the core of an excellent answer.

Comment: @walrus it'll take some more research than I can do at work, but I'll try to remember to do just that later today

Comment: @AllisonC We don't have those stores. The question as specifically for craft stores like Hobby Lobby or a place like Walmart, so, common stores.

Comment: @Achlys it's quite possible you do in fact have those stores, but haven't found them yet. They tend to not stand out unless you're actively looking for them. I can drive around for hours without seeing any, but we have at least a dozen in the area where I live, IF I know where they are. Where I used to live, there was one right down the street that I didn't know about until I walked into it one day for something else (it was, in fact, a craft store with an extensive theatrical section).

Comment: Fancy dress and party supplies shops sometimes also have small sections for related materials, like magic props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its been a while and I found my own answer.

As an alternative to spirit gum I've found that name brand **Eyelash Glue** (glue intended for use attaching fake eyelashes) works as an alternative, though the cheap stuff does not. The cheaper Eyelash Glues does't hold up well and the prosthetic is easily pulled off with the most minimal of force, making it a bad choice if one intends on wearing the prosthetic anywhere that there is a chance it will be brushing up against anything (like walls, tree branches, etc.)

The best alternative I've found is **Nail Glue** (Glue intended for attaching fake nails). The nail glue is relatively cheap. It holds as well as spirit gum but it is also just as easy to remove the prosthetic once you're done as it is when using spirit gum. It does not appear to have damaged the prosthetic either.

Both Eyelash Glue and Nail Glue are readily available where ever make up is sold, including Walmart, Target, CVS and Walgreens.

Answer (score 1):

This [article from Popular Mechanics](https://www.popularmechanics.com/culture/movies/a6182/diy-halloween-tips-let-me-in/) suggests using corn syrup thickened with flour. I found it while looking for a recipe to make spirit gum, which should be possible using rubbing alcohol and rosin (the latter is available from music shops as violinists use it). But I failed to find the proportions.

[Other sources](https://www.bustle.com/articles/184343-9-products-to-use-instead-of-sfx-makeup-for-last-minute-halloween-looks) suggest an adhesive intended for false lashes.

Comment: I wonder how well the corn syrup and flour mixture would hold up when exposed to body heat and sweat — but what an interesting alternative idea!

Comment: @Erica I thought that too, but they were quoting a pro.  On the other hand maybe in the pro world it can be touched up between scenes/takes